# A "Theorem Style" Problem Book in Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, problem-solving, book-recommendation, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to teach myself differential geometry using Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

To test my understanding, and learn the subject better, I am looking for a good problem book in differential geometry.

The kind of problems I am looking for are non-computational ones. The problems which are very much like theorems in themselves.

The best I can describe the kind of book I am looking for is something like *Berkeley's Problems in Mathematics* is for undergraduate mathematics.

The problems are not too hard. But each problem teaches something nice.

Comment: I am unaware of such a *book*, but...this site is a fairly good first-order approximation of what you are describing. Physics Forums used to also be decent, but I haven't been there in a while.

Comment: By 'this' site you mean mathstackexchange?

Comment: Yes, I mean Math StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

Try this new arrival:

Springer Link

*Smooth Manifolds*
Authors: Rajnikant Sinha

ISBN: 978-81-322-2103-6 (Print) 978-81-322-2104-3 (Online)